Sql Query map to two list of one model by dapper
I have two table REQUEST and PERSON
Request has two column of customer and lawyer both of them link to Person
Now I create a model that has two property that their types are Person
How write  TSQL  that result of join of Request & customer map to this two properties of model .
    `select request.id,personjoin1.data
                 CustomerData ,personjoin2.data LawyerData`

get following model
 ` public class{
   public int requestId{get;set;}
    public Person Customer{get;set;}
   public Person Lawyer{get;set;}
   }`

